# Automatic type creation from payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I cam across the below code which I haven't seen before, which is pretty neat:

```
@app.post("/posts")
def create_posts(payLoad: dict = Body(...)):
    print(payLoad['title'], payLoad['content'])
```

This is from FastAPI. How does it automatically extract the payload into a dictionary? If I just do `create_posts(payLoad)` it doesn't do it automatically. Also, what is the difference between doing `Body(...)` and `Body()` or `Body` ? All seem to work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than I am explaining here, but high level it works like this. There are two phases; app startup and request incoming.

### 1) App startup

When you start up a new FastAPI application, FastAPI identifies all routes (`APIRoute`). Your endpoint will be included as an `APIRoute` on the main application. When adding this route to your application the following happens:

- The route has a resolver for dependants (read: parameters), which loops over all parameters of your path operation function (`create_posts`) using inspection of the signature.
- Based on the type (`dict`) of the parameter (`payLoad`) and it's default value (instance of `Body()`), FastAPI saves this information for that parameter in a `Dependant` on this APIRoute.

So, the resolving of "what type is parameter `x` in this route?" happens on startup and initialization of the application and corresponding `APIRoute`s.

### 2) Request comes in

Then a request comes in:

- Uvicorn calls ASGI app (FastAPI in applications.py)
- FastAPI calls the route (APIRoute in routing.py)
- When the APIRoute is called (it's its own ASGI application) by FastAPI, it will try to resolve all 'dependencies' of the path operation function (create_posts). This is where FastAPI will try and resolve the `payLoad` parameter to the type `dict`, based on the inspection it performed earlier and stored as `Dependant`.
- FastAPI performs some logic (you could've given config to `Body()`) to cast the incoming request body to the respective parameters (`payLoad`). (this happens in dependencies/ultils.py in the function `request_body_to_args`).
- It returns the value (now a dict) and inserts that in the path operation function. That path operation function returns a value which is then cast to a `Response`.

Hope this clarifies a bit. It's quite complicated to follow a request around in the code base, but overall it's quite neat to be honest!

EDIT2: I missed one of your questions:

> Also, what is the difference between doing Body(...) and Body() or Body ?

`Body(...)` and `Body()` are the same thing. We used to have pass the `...` but recently a version (i believe it was 0.77) was released that accepted ommitting the placeholder. Upon start of the application, `Body()` is called (it's a function) which will return an object (also called `Body`). The latter is referenced in the `Dependant` that is stored on the route. This allows, for example, for the autogeneration of OpenAPI. The use of `Body` (so referencing it as an function object rather than calling the function itself), I haven't seen before and is not intended behavior.